# nestjs winston log file is written with colors encoding

Tags: nestjs, winston, express-winston

I am facing the same issue as https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1416 where `logger.info('Hello there. How are you?');` is resulting `�[32minfo�[39m: �[32mHello there. How are you?�[39m`

I don't know where `colorize` is so that I can remove it, here is my code:

```
  new winston.transports.File({
    format: winston.format.combine(
      winston.format.colorize({ // I added this but it's still not helping
        all: false,
        message: false,
        level: false,
      }),
      winston.format.label({ label: 'API' }),
      winston.format.timestamp(),
      winston.format.printf(({ level, message, label, timestamp }) => {
        return `${timestamp} [${label}] ${level}: ${message}`;
      }),
    ),
    filename: environment.logDirectory,
    level: 'http',
    maxsize: 1024 * 1024 * 10,
  }),
```

In `main.ts`, I have

```
import { WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER } from 'nest-winston';
app.useLogger(app.get(WINSTON_MODULE_NEST_PROVIDER));
```

In `AppModule.ts`, I have the following:

```
import { WinstonModule } from 'nest-winston';
...
    WinstonModule.forRoot({
      transports,
    }),
```

I can't find anywhere that uses `colorize()` and I don't know how can I disable it.

I am using `"nest-winston": "^1.4.0",` and `"winston": "^3.3.3",`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add **winston.format.uncolorize()** method to the formatting options to strip color encoding from your winston output

```
  format: winston.format.combine(
     winston.format.uncolorize()
     ...
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot @MrARC, this answered and solved my question.